# Certificate auto installation for SSL communication [Client]

Tags: apache, tomcat, ssl, https, client-certificates

I have Tomcat-Apache set up to serve my application using 443(Apache).
Configured Apache for root certificate and key for enabling HTTPS access for my application.

On server i had to install this certificate to user personal store for HTTPS access.

Problem is if client wants to access  he needs to manually install the certificate first. These are self signed certificates generated via openSSL.

```
openssl req -new -x509 -days 1024 -key ca.key -out ca.crt -config openssl.cnf
```

Is there a way to configure Apache, or install certificate in another store for client to trigger auto installation of certificate while accessing the site?

Comment: What software is the client using?

Comment: Client will be accessing website hosted via apache